# Can an object be notified when a component object changes in Angular 2/4?

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular2-databinding

In Angular, a component can receive as `@Input()` a variable or object.  Whenever the variable changes, Angular notifies the component.  Very cool...

I'm trying to build an app that shows a `ng2-tree` view on the left, and an edit-view on the right.  When the user clicks on a node in the tree, the details of that item is displayed on the right, and the user can change properties of that item.  What I need is for those changes to propagate back to the tree.

The individual nodes in the tree are an `ItemTreeNode`:

```
export class ItemTreeNode implements TreeModel {
  value: string;
  id: string;
  children: Array<ItemTreeNode>;
  icon: string;
  settings: TreeModelSettings;
  loadChildren;

  constructor(
    private itemService: ItemService,
    private parent_id: string,
    public item: Item
  ){ ... }
}
```

The tree renders the node using `.value` for the name.  This is set during the constructor by calling `this.item.nodeName()`.  Once set, it doesn't change.  The problem is, it needs to change whenever the item is changed.

What I'm looking for is a way for this object to be notified if the item changes, so that the `value` property can be updated.

Is there a way for the `ItemTreeNode` to "watch" the item and receive a callback if it ever changes, as part of Angular's change detection cycle?

Or is there a better way of implementing the desired behavior?

Comment: Yes you can look at [Shared Services](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) or [Ngrx](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/ngrx)

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with the help of RxJs. Let's interrupt Item's name setting via setter and trigger an Observable `.next()`.

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

class Item {
  private _name: string;
  private nameSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  name$ = this.nameSource.asObservable();

  set name(name: string) {
    this._name = name;
    this.nameSource.next(name);
  } 

  get name() { return this._name; } 

  getNodeName() { return this._name + ' !!!'; }

  constructor(name: string){
    this._name = name;
  }
}
```

You see, I push the original Item's name on `this.nameSource.next(name)`. In my example I assume that Item's name and the Node's name are defferent. Observable `$name` is public, it is for external subscriptions. Then I need to subscribe on Item's name change, and the best place for this is the ItemTreeNode constructor which gets an Item instance as a parameter:

```
class Node {
  value: string;

  constructor(item: Item) {
    item.name$.subscribe(result => this.value = item.getNodeName());
  }
}
```

Here the `result` is the Item's new name, but since it's not the same as Item's Node name, I do an extra call `.getNodeName()`. So the only thing you need to do is to pass Item's instance to Node's constructor, and then RxJs does the binding magic for you.

```
this.item = new Item('My Name');
const node = new Node(this.item);
```

That's all, I creatred a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UXwai8?p=preview) to demonstrate this approach.